# NVidia drivers don't work properly: `Failed to load module "nvidia" (module doesn't support this OS, 0)`

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, 20.04

I'm using a fresh installation of Xubuntu 20.04, on a laptop with a discrete NVidia card (GeForce 610M).
I didn't touch the video driver settings at all (except enabling proprietary drivers when installing).

The problem is that GLX doesn't work:

```
holyblackcat@hbc-laptop:~$ glxinfo
name of display: :0.0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

Here are the Xorg logs:

```
holyblackcat@hbc-laptop:/etc/X11$ grep -i nvidia /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[   117.912] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   117.914] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/libglx.so
[   117.918] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   117.918] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  390.132  Fri Nov  1 04:00:46 PDT 2019
[   117.918] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   117.918] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
[   117.919] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   117.919] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  390.132  Fri Nov  1 03:36:28 PDT 2019
[   117.919] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[   117.919] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" to /dev/dri/card1
[   117.919]   loading driver: nvidia
[   118.057] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[   118.057] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   118.057] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
[   118.057] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   118.057] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[   118.057] (II) Unloading nvidia
[   118.057] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module doesn't support this OS, 0)
[   118.058] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  390.132  Fri Nov  1 03:36:28 PDT 2019
[   118.058] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[   118.058] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[   118.146] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
[   118.316] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event11)
[   118.316] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event12)
[   118.317] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event13)
[   118.317] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event14)
```

I tried running `sudo nvidia-xconfig` and rebooting.

It didn't fix the GLX issue, and it made things even worse: The system switched to a tiny resolution, which I couldn't change even after deleting `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (which was generated by `nvidia-xconfig`) and rebooting.

I've switched to the Noveau driver for now, which fixed those problems.

Comment: Please uninstall all nvidia drivers and then install only the most recent one.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Can't believe the solution was so simple. Will you write it as an answer, or should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please uninstall *all* nvidia drivers and then install *only* the most recent one.

Comment: In case anyone needs more specific instructions: I've uninstalled all packages that had the word `nvidia` in their names, then did `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440` (which seems to currently be the newest of `nvidia-driver-XX` packages). It doesn't show up in the "settings->drivers", so I had to install it from the terminal.